# Using StringReplace to make file names

Tags: string-manipulation

Often I'm making many plots for different values of parameters. Each plot has a nice `PlotLabel` with superscripts, subscripts and some special characters. I would like to take this plot label and turn it into an acceptable, readable and unique file name.

Here is an example of a plot label

```
ac= {63425, 63433, 63432, 83, 117, 112, 101, 114, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, \
116, 66, 111, 120, 91, 63433, 947, 63424, 44, 32, 63433, 50, 63424, \
93, 63424, 32, 97, 116, 32, 83, 105, 110, 91, 920, 93, 32, 63425, \
63433, 63432, 83, 117, 112, 101, 114, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, \
66, 111, 120, 91, 63433, 120, 63424, 44, 32, 63433, 50, 63424, 93, \
63424, 32, 63425, 63433, 63432, 83, 117, 98, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, \
116, 66, 111, 120, 91, 63433, 121, 63424, 44, 32, 63433, 115, 117, \
98, 63424, 93, 63424};
a = FromCharacterCode[ac]
```

I had a hard time copying in the string that I wanted so I made a list of Characters.

The following `StringReplace` is a start but I would like much better.

```
newA=StringReplace[a,{
 " "->"-",
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("~~f_~~"\), \("~~d__~~"\)]\)"  :>f<>"_"<>d,
 "\!\(\*SubsuberscriptBox[\("~~f_~~"\), \("~~d__~~"\), \("~~u_~~"\)]\)" :>f<>"_"<>d<>"^"<>u,
 "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\("~~f_~~"\), \("~~u_~~"\)]\)"  :>f<>"^"<>u
}];
newA=ToString[newA,CharacterEncoding->"PrintableASCII"]
```

This is a start but nothing that I can use yet. One of the things I would like to do is replace special characters with there long names like turning:

```
 \[Gamma]^2-at-Sin[\[CapitalTheta]]-x^2-y_sub
```

into

```
Gamma^2-at-Sin[CapitalTheta]-x^2-y_sub
```

I'm also looking at using `TeXForm` then doing some `StringReplace` on that output.

How have others converted complex text into file names?

**LabelToFile**
Using what bbgodfrey suggested here is a first cut at a function to do what I want:

```
 Clear[LabelToFile];
 Options[LabelToFile]={"Sub"->"_","Super"->"^","Point"->"p"};
 LabelToFile[a_?StringQ,opts:OptionsPattern[LabelToFile]]:=Module[
 {newA,sub,sup,pt},

 sub=OptionValue["Sub"];
 If[!StringQ[sub],sub="_"];

 sup=OptionValue["Super"];
 If[!StringQ[sup],sup="^"];

 pt=OptionValue["Point"];
 If[!StringQ[pt],pt="p"];


 newA=StringReplace[a,{
    Shortest["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\("~~f__~~"\), \("~~d__~~"\)]\)" ] :>f<>sub<>d,
    Shortest["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\("~~f__~~"\), \("~~u__~~"\)]\)" ] :>f<>sup<>u,
    Shortest["\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\("~~f__~~"\), \("~~d__~~"\), \("~~u__~~"\)]\)"]:>f<>sub<>d<>sup<>u}];
 newA=ToString[newA,CharacterEncoding->"PrintableASCII"];
 newA=StringReplace[newA,{
 Shortest["\\[Capital"~~z__~~"]"]:>z,
 Shortest["\\["~~z__~~"]"]:>ToLowerCase[z],
 " "->"-",
 "."->pt
 }];
 Return[newA]
 ];
```

Comment: In light of the number of contortions you'll likely need to go through to ensure valid names, seems to me making a simple index file with the "pretty" form and a reference to a simple file name would be a whole lot easier...

Comment: I have certainly done that many times before and it works well for a set of plots that are similar and works very well when making an animation for a beamer where I can also have Mathematica write the LaTeX code. But when playing with parameters for plots that have to be manually copied PowerPoint it is nice to have a systematic way of generating human readable file names.

Answer (score 3):

The command,

```
StringReplace[newA, Shortest["\\[" ~~ z__ ~~ "]"] :> z]
```

replaces strings like `\[string]` by `string`.  In particular, it transforms newA to

```
Gamma^2-at-Sin[CapitalTheta]-x^2-y_sub
```

as requested.  Of course, this procedure will not work, if the string itself contains `\\[` or `]`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it by hand, using a convention something like this:

```
filename[ac] = "gamma_2_at_sin_theta_x_2_y"
```

If you have so many outputs that you can't do it by hand, use some kind of index file as per @rasher.

I don't think you should do this automatically, because it will be very difficult to write a safe robust general case that avoids difficult characters in file names, and produces comprehensible useful output.  It's possible but not an instructive use of mathematica.